# Voice(Audio file) properties to be changed to get another Voice

Tags: android, c, audio

I am trying to do an Android App i.e Voice Changer:(link shared below)
[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baviux.voicechanger&hl=en]
I have found all the native libraries to change the audio voice file to another voice
But i don't know the exact values of audio properties to be changed to get the type of given voice as any one of below ones:

• Helium
• Robot
• Big robot
• Squirrel
• Dizzy
• Backwards
• Monster
• Nervous
• Giant
• Telephone
• Cave
• Cathedral
• Dark side
• Alien
• Grand Canyon
• Fan
• Devil
• Child
• Sheep
• Overlord
• Small alien
• Megaphone
• Death
• Everything is spinning
• Hexafluoride
• Small creature
• Optimus Robot
• Android
• Villain
• Battery low
• Shrinking
• Cyborg
• Duck
• Extraterrestrial
• Deep voice
• Zombie

can any one help me what exact values(properties) of audio file like Pitch,Frequency etc... for above voice types to be get changed using the native libraries

Comment: @santhosh did you find solution for this??

Comment: Have you got the solution of your question?